# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update2 - Load testing - Missing Manifest

Tags: visual-studio-2013, automated-tests, load-testing, azure-devops

I have created a Web/Load test and whilst running the newly created WebTest works as expected, if I add that to a Load test, locally it executes but does not testing.  If I push it up to TFS-Online I get a Manifest dialog error.

The path is long and does not exist but sits within appdata\local\assembly.  The end of it is CommonExtension\Microsoft\Webclient\TestServiceplugin\TestStatus.json not found.

I have repaired my new install of Visual Studio but still the same error, I have two references in the project: Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTestFramework, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework, am I missing anything?

Possibly related is if I try to open Load Test Manager from the Load Test Menu, I get an Exception dialog of Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

An online search has drawn a blank, anyone seen this or know how I can troubleshoot?

Steve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help on the MS Forums, it has now been resolved but not particularly clear what the exact issue was.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d3009f05-e848-4bdc-a929-4648f38fb11a/visual-studio-2013-ultimate-update2-load-testing-missing-manifest?forum=TFService&prof=required

Hopefully helps others with this or similar random issue as re-installs did not fix it.

Steve.

Comment: Steve, I looked at the link to see if it would help my own similar problem but mine is happening locally. No TFS involved. I get this when running any webtest or loadtest that I created in the project. Did you ever see the problem in that scenario? (Because I'm also finding nothing else on the web but this post). Thanks!

Comment: No, it seems to be some kind of config issue but MS never identified it.  Have you tried the various cache clearing processes?  Other than that you could try a local version of what I did.  You can open a new solution and add a new test and run it.  If its the same issue as me, that will work.  You can then switch back to yours and hopefully that just starts working.  Its a quirky one but no idea why it behaves the way it does.

Comment: New solutions/new tests/ nothing worked. I ended up completely uninstalling VS2013 and then reinstalling and reapplying Update 3 and voila it worked!Thanks for the reply. :)